How to align view to uneven/irregular face to maintain straight/horizontal orientation? (without the need of rolling/rotating view afterwards)
I want to align view to uneven face with angled edges and maintain straight orientation of the view as well.

When I align view to active face it doesn't stay straight and rolls/rotates to the side. It seems like it aligns to the angled edge for some reason. Any solution for this?

Conclusion:
When aligning to uneven face Blender uses some kind of average, which results in arbitrary view orientation. Aligning to the specific edge allows to control view orientation.
The reason Blender rotates the view when aligning to an uneven face is that it uses the average normal of the face, leading to arbitrary orientation. By selecting a specific edge, you gain more control and can achieve a straight alignment more easily without needing to adjust the view later.
This method gives you more precision and avoids the need for additional steps to roll or rotate the view after alignment.

Not sure that I understand what you want, but have you tried selecting the face and then Shift->Numpad 7? If you want to align it to an edge, select the edge and use the same keys. I tried this on a plane I hacked up to, I think, somewhat resemble your object.

Yes. I did use Shift Numpad 7 to align view to face. This is what last image shows.
I don't want to align view to edge, but doing so actually results in desire effect and aligns view with face in straight position, so your comment is best solution at the moment. Thanks.

With the caveat that this suggestion comes only from experience, (it isn't documented, and I haven't hunted down the code,) the active edge will be aligned to View Y.
So you can select any 2 edges to ShiftNumpad 7 align your view to the implied plane, with the active edge vertical:


Thanks to Markus von Broady:
✲ CtrlShiftNumpad 7 will align from the opposite side (on the GIF below alternating with and without ✲ Ctrl):

And afterwards you can press ⬆ ShiftNumpad 4 12 times to rotate 180°:


Afterwards you can press shift + numpad 4 until you rotated 180°

@MarkusvonBroady Of course. I forget this one because I have Ctrl-Shift-Mousewheel set to roll the camera...( which is why it doesn't work for me?) If you're confident this is the default, feel free to edit. I can't check, easily.

@RobinBetts Aligning view to active edge results in aligning view to face. Although it have to be specific edge to achieve straight orientation of face.
Seems like there is no need to select additional edge for alignment and doing so requires additional steps to roll/rotate view to fix face orientation.
So aligning view to specific edge seems like the best solution at the moment to achieve straight position/orientation of face view alignment.  Thanks.

@healthyfat True ... for an un-shared edge? I think I (and possibly Markus) were trying to as be as general as possible. But for the case you show, sure, that's quicker. Plus, I reckon a modeller should always have 'Create Orientation' in their quick menu. Any 2 points will make an edge, or 3 points a plane, to orient transforms, (Y is along an edge)
